# running Tendermint in aws ec2 instance

Tags: tendermint

I am trying to run Tendermint in distributed mode in two different aws EC2 instance. 
I have completed the Installation procedures from this article - 
https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/blob/master/docs/introduction/install.md

every time I try to run, `tendermint node`

it is throwing an error..
`abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query err="dial tcp 127.0.0.1:26658: connect: connection refused"`

I want to run in distributed mode.

what is the reason behind it ? any suggestions and solutions ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still running into this issue? By distributed do you mean two different nodes or tendermint on one server and the other server has the state machine?

Could you try running tendermint node --proxy_app=kvstore or tendermint node --proxy_app=counter. Here is a guide for running tendermint out of process: https://docs.tendermint.com/master/guides/go.html

Comment: I am Stil facing this issue

Comment: running two docker instances on two different aws instances (added the seed and persistent peers of Machine-2 in Machine-1).. but this is not resolved yet. do we need to add validators in genesis.json file ??